# Canvas view crash the application on touch events

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying a simple CustomView with canvas. This custom view simply change the position of an icon picture on the screen randomly when is invoked `updatePosition()`, and in my intention should move the image on drag, scale on pinch... and when I touch a position in the screen should appear in the clicked position.

My try is the follow

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    Bitmap mBmp;
    Random mRnd;
    Paint mPaint;

    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    int w, h, bw, bh;
    int px = -1, py = -1;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
        mBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.icon);

    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);

        mBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.icon); 
        bw = mBmp.getWidth(); 
        bh = mBmp.getHeight();
        mPaint = new Paint(); 
        mPaint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mRnd = new Random();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        Log.d("DEBUG", "X: " + mPosX + " Y: " + mPosY);
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);

        if (px == -1 && py == -1) { 
            px = w / 2 - bw / 2; 
            py = h / 2 - bh / 2; 
        }

        canvas.drawCircle(px + (bw / 2), py + (bh / 2), 70, mPaint); 
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBmp, px, py, null); 

        canvas.restore();

    }

    public void updatePosition() {
        px = mRnd.nextInt(w - bw);
        py = mRnd.nextInt(h - bh);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        h = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                invalidate();
            }

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

updatePosition() listener works while onTouchListener cause crash of the application with a NullPointerException if I try to drag the image or touch any position of the screen

Could someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `mScaleDetector` is only initialized in one of the constructor. It should be initialized in all constructors. A common pattern is to create an `init()` method and place all you initializing in there then call that method from all constructors.

Note: It's always helpful to post a StackTrace... You should be able to see which constructor got called.

Comment: Alternatively, just forward the constructors with `this()` as in the first one and move all initialization to the fullest one (taking 3 params).

Comment: Thanks.I have followed your suggestion and now the drag works, without any crash but the image does't appear in the touched position moves only when I drag, I want also that *teleports* in the touched position

Comment: @AndreaF you should create another question for that issue.

Comment: @J.Romero
Ok
I have created another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006147/teleport-the-image-in-the-touched-position-in-canvas

I'll be glad if you help me to solve also this problem